# New Golden Ratio Conjecture with Triangle and Square: It is very close, but is it really the golden ratio?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, golden-ratio

Geogebra gives me 1.616 for the ratio of the blue segment p to the red segment q instead of the golden ratio 1.618 for the construction shown below, so it could be close to PHI, but no cigar.

This construct is created by drawing a square and then drawing an equilateral triangle with one vertex touching the side of the square as drawn.

A diagonal (segment n) is then drawn from D to F, cutting the square at H.

Segment q extends from C to H and segment extends from C to G.

Is the ratio of the blue segment p to the red segment q the golden ratio?  I have my doubts, but it is so very close.

Thanks and best regards! :)

[image: New Golden Ratio Conjecture with Triangle and Square:]

Comment: $p=2\sqrt3,\frac{q}{4}=\frac{4}{4+p}$, so $\frac{p}{q}=\frac{\sqrt3(\sqrt3+2)}{4}\approx1.616$

Comment: Congratulations on reaching a rep of $100\pi$! :)

Comment: Is $GF$ parallel to $BC$?

Comment: @mathlove yes GF is parallel to BC! :)

Comment: thanks @Blue!  :) Thanks for all your help and insights too! :)

Comment: Hmmm ... You've been down-voted to below $100\pi$. I didn't down-vote, but I can see why one might: It's *dead-simple* ---using coordinates and the height of an equilateral triangle--- to confirm that the ratio isn't $\phi$. (BTW: It takes a *much* more elaborate construction for computational error to be a factor in GeoGebra.) It's great that you started using GeoGebra to weed-out faulty constructions that only looked correct in Illustrator; going forward, you should put more (some?) effort into (dis-)proving things yourself, to further filter-out trivial posts that risk annoying folks here.

Comment: Thanks @Blue!  Yes, geogebra should give PHI to all the decimal places when it is there.  Yes will be seeking to disprove more "Close ones."  I really didn't think this one existed.

Comment: @AstrophysicsMath: *"I really didn't think this one existed."* Then, to be blunt: **You should not have posted.** Your $\phi$ posts are numerous, so simply *reading* them takes someone a non-trivial amount of time. Please respect your readers (and answerers) by making each post *count*.

Comment: thanks @Blue, will heed this advice in the future. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your diagram

- C seems to be at $(4,4)$
- G seems to be at $(4+2\sqrt3,4)$
- H seems to be at $(4,-12+8\sqrt3 )$

Which makes $p=2\sqrt3$ and $q=16-8\sqrt3$ and $\dfrac{p}{q}=\dfrac34+\dfrac{\sqrt3}2 \approx 1.616025$ which is slightly less than the golden ratio $\dfrac12+\dfrac{\sqrt5}2 \approx  1.618034$